# CakePHP Save Date/Time on Login

Tags: php, cakephp, datetime, controller, save

I have the bellow login function in my controller and am trying to save the login date/time into the users database table under the field last_login  that is a DATETIME field, login works fine but the field never gets populated.. any ideas on what may be stopping this or how to troubleshoot what should be getting output?

```
public function login() {
    $this->layout = 'login';
    if ($this->request->is('post')) {
        if ($this->Auth->login()) {

            $this->User->id = $this->Auth->user('id'); // target correct record
            $this->User->saveField('last_login', date(DATE_ATOM)); // save login time

            $this->redirect($this->Auth->redirect());
        } else {
            $this->Session->setFlash('Invalid username or password, try again', 'default', array('class' => 'warning'));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your last_login field in db is set to `DATETIME` then, you need to do:

```
$this->User->saveField('last_login', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));
```

As `DATE_ATOM` returns something like `2012-08-15T15:52:01+00:00`, so it wont get inserted
Try disabling AuthComponent::autoRedirect, like

```
public $components = array(
    'Auth' => array(
        ......
        'autoRedirect' => false  //set to false to disable auto redirect
    ),
);
```

Comment: it is still not updating that field, i even attempted to change the field to varchar so it would save something but it never gets touched.. and cakephp never outputs any errors.

Comment: @medoix Set debug level to 2 and check what SQL query the call to `saveField()` generates. Don't forget to comment `$this->redirect()` or you won't see the SQL queries of the `login` action.

Comment: i disabled the redirect and it still redirects, i even placed a die('setting date'); after the saveField and it is not even getting to it i found. it appears as tho if ($this->Auth->login()) { just redirects instantly without doing anything bellow in the IF statement...

Comment: @medoix try disabling AuthComponent's autoReirect by setting to false, then your db update after login should work fine.. see udated answer

Comment: i have tried that and still auto redirecting to main page after login, i even set a die('setting date'); after the set command it does not die, just continues on into the main page.

Comment: It is the following line that is stopping it, i place a die after this line and it does not die, i place one before it and it dies correctly inside the if statement. I also comment this line out and everything else works....$this->User->saveField('last_login', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"));

Comment: try:: $this->User->last_login = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

Comment: turns out my id field in the DB was not set to auto increment and the first user had an ID of 0 instead of 1 therefore it was spitting out an exception.

Answer (score 1):

```
Use this to print query:

$log = $this->User->getDataSource()->getLog(false, false);
debug($log);
exit;
```

Comment: anything i put after the saveField line does not get run if that line is uncommented... how do i debug a line that is causing this issue? If i put a die() before that line the login function dies... so weird.

Comment: Try: $this->User->saveField('last_login', date("Y-m-d H:i:s"), false);   The 'false' is used to set any validations in the model to false in case validations are responsible for non-execution of query.

Comment: Here is another way to do the same thing:                                                                            `$this -> data = Array ( 'User' => Array ( 'id' => $this->Auth->user('id') , 'last_login' => date ('Y-m-d H:i:s') ) );                               $this -> User -> save ($this -> data))`